# Converting a large ASCII to CSV file in python or java or something else on Linux or Win7

Tags: java, php, python, csv, ascii

Need a hint so I can convert a huge (300-400 mb) ASCII file to a CSV file.

My ASCII file is a database with a lot of products (about 600,000 pcs = 55,200,000 lines in the file).

Below is ONE product. It is like a tablerow in a database, with 88 columns.
If you count the below lines, there is 92 lines.

For every time we have the '00I+CR\LF' it indicates, that we have a new row/product.

Each line is ended with a CR+LF.

A whole product/row is ended with the following three lines:

```
A00
A10
A21
```

-as shown below.

Between the starting line `'00I CR+LF'` and the three ending lines, we have lines, starting with 2 digits (column name), and what comes after those digits, is the data for the column.

If we take the first line below the starting line `'00I CR+LF'` we will see:

`'0109321609'`. `01` indicates that it is the column named 01, and the rest is the data stored in that column: `'09321609'`.

I want to strip out the two digits, indicating each column name/line-number, so the first line (after the starting indication `'00I'`): `0109321609` comes out as the following: `”09321609”`.

Putting it together with the next line (`02`), it should give an output like:

```
”09321609”,”15274”, etc.
```

When coming to the end, we want a new row.

The first line `'00I'` and the three last lines `'A00'`, `'A10'` and `'A21'` we don't want to be included in the output file.

Here is how a row looks like (every line is ended by a CR+LF):

```
00I
0109321609
0215274
032
0419685
05
062
072
081
09
111
121
15
161
17
1814740
1920120401
2020120401
2120120401
22
230
240
251
26BLAHBLAH 1000MG
27
281
29
30
31BLAHBLAH 1000 mg Filmtablets Hursutacinzki
32
3336
341
350
361
371
401
410
420
43
445774
45FTA
46
47AN03AX14
48BLAHBLAH00000000000000000000010
491
501
512
522
5317
542
552
561
572
581
591
60
61
62
631
641
65
66
67
681
69
721
74884
761
771
780
790
801
811
831
851474
86
871
880
891
901
911
922
930
941
951
961
97
98
990
A00
A10
A21
```

Anyone got a hint on how it can be converted?

The file is too big for a webserver with `php` and `mysql` to run. My thought was to put the file in a directory on my local server, and read the file, strip out the line numbers, and insert the data directly in a `mysql` database on the fly, but the file is too big, and the server stalls.

I'm able to run under Linux (Ubuntu) and Windows 7.

Maybe some python or java is recommended? I'm able to run both, but my experience with those is low, but I'm a quick learner, so if someone can give a hint?  :-)

Best Regards
Bjarke :-)

Comment: why do you want an output file? wouldn't it be better to put this data in a database instead?

Comment: A CSV file is an ASCII file as well.

Comment: You mentioned you're a quick learner, so I suggest you look through the docs of Python [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module. It will probably be enough for the conversion part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are *absolutely certain* that each entry is 92 lines long:

```
from itertools import izip
import csv

with open('data.txt') as inf, open('data.csv','wb') as outf:
    lines = (line[2:].rstrip() for line in inf)
    rows = (data[1:89] for data in izip(*([lines]*92)))
    csv.writer(outf).writerows(rows)
```

Comment: That helped. Not using assert. Thanks. But how did you tell, that the first line in the file, starting with '00I' not is included? That I don't figure out yet. Will study a bit more on the docu page from python to find out :-) I can see how you say that we don't need the first 2 digits on each line - striping them out. Can also see how you tell that we then collect data from line 1 to 89, skipping the rest of the lines up to 92, putting them all in a row, and finaly output to file. 
Does python start counting linenumbers at 0 and not 1 ? If so, I understand all :-)

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this in python.

```
import csv
fo = csv.writer(open('out.csv','wb'))
with open('eg.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        assert line[:3] == '00I'
        buf = []
        for i in range(88):
            line = f.next()
            buf.append(line.strip()[2:])

        line = f.next()
        assert line[:3] == 'A00'
        line = f.next()
        assert line[:3] == 'A10'
        line = f.next()
        assert line[:3] == 'A21'
        fo.writerow(buf)
```

Comment: that makes sense to me, added  `#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
to the file, because I had the CR+LF at the end of every line in the file, wich was indicated by a non-ascii thing.  So, now i ran the script, and got a error, without any - for me as beginner to python - usefull debug info:   File "./conv.py", line 8, in <module>
    assert line[:3] == '00I'
AssertionError   ... Note: I named the file conv.py .

Comment: Maybe the problem with the assertation error is while the line in the source-file '00I' ends with a '\xc2' ? BTW, I'm not using coding: utf-8 but ascii.

Comment: i used assert because you sounded like you  are absolutely sure about intput file's structure.  replace the assert statement with if statement and dump the line in the if block, see what you read.  you can even dump every line for debugging purpose.

Comment: also, is cr+lf is ascii code 13 and 10? (aka dos file format)?  i never had to worry about unix/dos things when i read python.   i think that coding things is about your python script, not about the data file.